# WP_Editor - Setting render location on page

Tags: wp-editor

I'm trying to include [wp_editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) in a settings page.

```
public function addEditor($content = '')
{       
    $editor_id = 'createposteditor';

    $args = array(
        'textarea_rows' => 15,
        'teeny' => true,
        'quicktags' => false,
        'editor_class' => 'createpost-editor'
    );

    return wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $args  );
}
```

and then I echo it out on the settings page:

```
<tr>                    
    <td align="left" scope="row">                                                                 

        <h1>Add content (optional)</h1>
        '. $poster->addEditor() .'                                           
    </td>
</tr>
```

My issue is, the editor always gets rendered at the top of the page, not from within the `<td>` as I require.

Comment: From the [source](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_editor/) it is absolutely clearly stated that this method ***renders*** the editor. You need to call it exactly where you want it. But to see your real problem you need to show the surroundings as well.

Comment: Yes, post the surrounding code. Something is wrong with the code you have. It is pasted as HTML but is almost certainly a PHP string.

Answer (score 1):

As kaiser has stated, you are attempting to return the the markup for an instance of the WP Editor, but you're using `wp_editor()` - a function that echos its output.

> From the
>   [source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) it
>   is absolutely clearly stated that this method renders the editor. You
>   need to call it exactly where you want it.